# Find two sequences which are orthogonal but not their limit

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I am stumbling upon this question I asked myself. We know that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are two sequences of a Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H},\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ such that
$$
\begin{equation}
x_n\rightharpoonup x \text{ and }y_n\to y
\end{equation}
$$
where $\rightharpoonup$ denotes the weak convergence, we have 
$$
\begin{equation}
\langle x_n,y_n\rangle\to\langle x,y\rangle
\end{equation}
$$

Now, what about if the two sequences are weakly convergent, that is we have 
$$
\begin{equation}
x_n\rightharpoonup x \text{ and }y_n\rightharpoonup y
\end{equation}
$$

Do we still have the result on the inner product convergence ?

Comment: Your counter example is good. What do you mean by another example? Pick $x_n=e_n, y_n = e_n+e_{n+1}$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, using another vector from the basis works., thank you! I was just wondering if we can create an example without using an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know an orthonormal basis weakly converges to $0$ because of Parseval equality:
if $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denotes an orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{H}$, then for all $f\in\mathcal{H}$, we have 
$$
f = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\langle f,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
with
$$
\Vert f\Vert^2=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\vert\langle f,e_n\rangle\vert^2
$$
As the sum converges, the term $\vert\langle f,e_n\rangle\vert^2$ has to converge to $0$. As it is the case for all $f\in\mathcal{H}$, we have $e_n\rightharpoonup 0$.

Thus, we define $x_n=y_n=e_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We have $x=y=0$ but $\langle x_n,y_n\rangle=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.